# Search/Replace Headers with Start/End Tokens in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am new to Python and I have a task where I need to sanitize headers in files in a particular way because there is no standard for my headers right now and I am trying to come up with this script to reuse for multiple instances

Sample File:

```
*_____________________________
* This is header text
* For details, see foobar.txt.
*_____________________________
*
*

* Code goes here
Code = x
```

The way I have to do this is by defining starting and ending position for the header and then scrub everything in between (start/end point included), before adding a new header.

Currently I am trying to use my

```
start_pos = r"*_____________________________"
end_pos = r"""*_____________________________
    *
    *"""
```

and then search for everything in the middle. I want to then concat altogether and then delete/replace to have my new file look like this:

```
*
* Hello, world.
*

* Code goes here
Code = x
```

Comment: @wp78de Yes! I was having trouble figuring out how to separate out the group in the middle. With a little bit of tweaking, I can make it work with other use cases as well. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, you can post that as a full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it comes:

```
\*_____________________________([\s\S]*?)\*_____________________________(?:\n\*){2}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sg7fU8/1)

To match the content in-between we can use a modified "dot" `[\s\S]` that matches everything across including newlines. The "dot" matches lazy to avoid matching too much.

[Sample Code](https://ideone.com/ah3k0U):

```
import re
regex = r"\*_____________________________([\s\S]*?)\*_____________________________(?:\n\*){2}"
test_str = ("*_____________________________\n"
    "* This is header text\n"
    "* For details, see foobar.txt.\n"
    "*_____________________________\n"
    "*\n"
    "*\n\n"
    "* Code goes here\n"
    "Code = x\n")
subst = "*\\n* Hello, world.\\n*"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)
```